# Computing Sequences with Addition Chains In pseudopolynomial time?

Tags: np-hardness, np-complete

Computing Sequence $a_1, \ldots, a_n$ with addition chains (CSAC) is the problem of finding the shortest sequence  $b_1, \ldots, b_m$ with the following properties:

1. $b_1=1$.
2. Every $b_i$ with $i>1$  is the sum of two previous numbers.
3. For every $a_j$ there exists $b_i$ s.t. $a_j=b_i$.

It is known that this problem is [NP-hard.](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/0210047)

**Question:** Is this problem has a pseudo-polynomial algorithm (i.e. polynomial in $a_1 + \ldots a_n$)?

UPD: I have understood that the problem is not trivial even if $n=1$.

Comment: It shouldn’t be NP hard because there’s always a solution of size polylog(N) where N is the sum of ai’s

Comment: @daniello the size of the solution depence on small $n$...

Comment: I mean the number of $b_i$’s that are not equal to any $a_j$‘s.

Comment: @daniello and why is it true?

Comment: It isn’t (or rather I don’t see a proof and expect it to be false). My mistake was to assume that once we have all the powers of 2 we can make every bi in just one operation, which is total bull.